# Pressing a key down using the function node

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have set up a simple line of code, and I would like to try to press a key, for example "w", down whenever a integer between 1 and 10 is detected. I am relatively new to node-red and dont have much knowledge. i've searched around a bit but cannot find any answers to my question, any help would be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be 2 nodes in the library (on https://flows.nodered.org) that might be able to do what you want.

1. https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-autokey
2. https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-sendkeys

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any documentation for either.

After quick look at code the first (node-red-contrib-autokey) it looks to use [robotjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs) and if you include `/key` in the `msg.topic` it will then "press" the key found in `msg.payload.key`

Details of key names can be found here https://robotjs.io/docs/syntax#keys